# PHP variable within an HTML query string

Tags: php, html

I have an ASP site, and I am tracking traffic. The header includes the line:

```
<img alt="" src="http://xxxxxxxxx.co.uk/pixel.asp?visitorreferringurl=<% =Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") %>" width="1" height="1" />
```

The target ASP page tracks the original referrer (from the passed query string) and the page the user is visiting (on the pixel.asp page this is actually the referer).

All is good.

I also have a Wordpress site (hence PHP) and I am trying to do the same. I can get pixel.asp to record but can't pass the referrer. I have tried..

```
<img alt="" src="http://xxxxxxx.co.uk/pixel.asp?visitorreferringurl<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" width="1" height="1" />
```

I also tried to declare the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` as a variable and then use that, but still no result.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Missing the "echo" in your <?php $_SERVER.... ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "echo" to output the variable. 
See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

```
[img alt="" src="http://xxxxxxx.co.uk/pixel.asp?visitorreferringurl=<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" width="1" height="1" /]"
```

Comment: Didn't realize this. Fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Thought I had tried that... but it works perfectly!

Comment: but you didn't spot the deliberate error.. the missing equals sign before the php code.

Comment: @Nick Bridgens included that for you. Would be great if you choose an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to output the information in your variable.

Try this:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
```

Additional information:

You don't need to close the `img` tag with a trailing slash, so `<img src="img">` is perfectly valid. Also, setting the `alt` attribute for the sake of setting it isn't useful, so either have some information there or drop it altogether.